# Язык C, сигнатура функции обратного вызова

Tags: c, callback

Подскажите, какова разница в следующих объявлениях:

1) Самое простое - функция, принимающая указатель на функцию, которая ничего не принимает и не возвращает.

```
void func( void (*_f)(void) );
```

2) Ошиблись со скобками, я долгое время считал, что этот вариант синонимичен предыдущему, но, на самом деле, нет. Вторая по счету скобка (и ее парная), по всей видимости, просто опускаются. В итоге получается функция, принимающая указатель на функцию, которая ничего не принимает и возвращает... указатель на **void**?

```
void func( void (*_f(void)) );
```

3) Некоторые говорят, что это синоним первого примера - функция, которая принимает функцию, которая ничего не принимает и не возвращает. Короче говоря, ситуация такая же, как с объявлением массивов - идентификатор **_f** в теле функции **func** будет обозначать указатель на функцию, которая ничего не принимает и не возвращает.

```
void func( void _f(void) );
```

Я уже задавал этот вопрос около года назад, но не смог отыскать его в истории. Возможно, он был удален.

Помогите разобраться со скобками и колл-бэк аргументами.

Comment: Ну вы все верно описали. Добавим, что имя функции всегда превращается в указатель на нее, и еще - https://cdecl.org/ вам в помощь...

Comment: То есть, вместо **1** варианта абсолютно законно можно использовать **3**? Он и короче, и понятнее...

Comment: Но тогда какова причина того, что в стандартных функциях используется первый вариант объявления? Например, функция генерации сигнала:  
void (*signal(int sign, void (*funcptr)(int)))(int);

Comment: Он строже, не полагается на неявное приведение, работает во всех версиях C. Imho :)

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
void f(void);
void f(void){}
void* g(void);
void* g(void){}

typedef void (* pf)(void) ;
typedef void (* pf2(void))  ;
typedef void  pf3(void) ;

int main(){
  pf p1 = f; pf p1_ = &f;
  pf2* p2 = g; pf2* p2_ = &g;
  pf3* p3 = f; pf3* p3_ = &f; }
```

Первый вариант это указатель на функцию `void->void`. Можно присваивать как имя или адрес имени - не имеет значения. Второго варианта в стандарте нет , поэтому круглые скобки убираются и получаем просто тип функции (не указатель на неё): `void->(void*)`. Чтобы был указатель на функцию добавляем звёздочку. Третий вариант это та-же функция `void->void` но не указатель а имя. По-этому добавляем звёздочку. Все три типа разные. Вызывать функции, сохранённый в виде указателей на них можно как со звёздочкой так и без (но обязательно с правильными скобками).

```
p1(); (*p1)();
p2(); (*p2)();
p3(); (*p3)();
```

Практического смысла на тип как функция (не указатель) нет. Потому-что переменных со значением функции не бывает. Есть только как указатель на функцию. По-этому и аргументы всегда передаются как указатель.

Comment: Если имеем **void func( void _f(void) ){}**, тогда в теле функции **func** идентификатор **_f** является указателем на функцию, которая ничего не принимает и не возвращает? Иначе говоря, правила такие же, как для аргумента-массива (указателя)? Например, **int arr[10]**; Здесь имя массива является указателем на массив из 10 элементов типа **int**.

Comment: `_f` как значение будет указателем на функцию. Неважно как передавали: `func(f)` или `func(&f)`. Внутри функции `func` значение `_f` будет указателем на эту функцию. НО `&_f` это адрес в стеке на локальную переменную. А `* * * * * _f` всё тот-же указатель на функцию.